# TortoiseSVN - Is there a warning about new files that are not tracked?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I'm used to `git` and its CLI so whenever I want to commit I always do a `git status` first to check for any new files I have forgotten to add, if any use `git add` and then do the committing and pushing. Qt Creator, which has a nice integration of this VCS, does all this automatically and if you add a new file to the folder where the git repo resides, when you commit you get a neat list of all new files that are not currently tracked and you can add these.

Imagine my surprise when I did multiple commits after adding a bunch of new files, then did a checkout to a different directory with my latest revision and found out that my new files are not there (though all the others that were tracked did show all my changes that I've committed).

I found out that TortoiseSVN does offer you the option to **Add file** or **Add folder** via the context menu in the repo browser. However for the love of God I was never ever warned that I have untracked files. It is of course my fault that I didn't research how things work (I've used SVN so long ago that I'm practically a complete beginner).

The question: is it possible to make TortoiseSVN warn me for any new filesor do I have to always do the "tracking" myself, add the new ones and then commit or whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no warning about uncommitted changes. But you can use TortoiseSVN **SVN commit** to check if there has uncommitted changes.

- If the box shows no files to commit, that means you have committed all the changes.

[image: 1]

- If the box shows files, you need to select the files and commit changes. There are three status for uncommitted file:

[image]

`Non-versioned`: you add the files in SVN.

`Modified`: files have version controlled by SVN and you made change on the files.

`Missing`: files have version controlled by SVN and you delete the files.

Comment: *facepalm* I have actually unchecked this at some point since my repository has a reference to an external one that I don't have writing access to. So in order to prevent an attempt to commit locally modified files that belong to that repo to that external one, I have disabled it so that I don't click on the non-versioned files by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use "Check for Modifications" in the context menu.

[image: SVN Context Menu]

Check for Modification Window will show the Unversioned , Modified files in the local SVN copy . Additionally We can also use "Check Repository" option in the window to view the versions that are committed by other users that are not yet updated.

[image: Check for Modification Window]